# Помогите сделать сортировку

Tags: c#

Нужно сделать сортировку двух массивов одновременно (товары и цены). Сортируется цена по убыванию, а вместе с ней и товары. Функция `sort` выдает ошибку выполнения. Помогите исправить.

```
struct Obj
{
    public string value1;
    public int value2;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] Products = new string[4] { "Meat", "Bread", "Milk", "Chocolate" };
    int[] Prices = new int[4] { 25, 4, 10, 16 };
    Obj[] objs = new Obj[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(Products[i] + "\n" + Prices[i] + "\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        objs[i] = new Obj();
        objs[i].value1 = Products[i];
        objs[i].value2 = Prices[i];
    }
    Array.Sort(objs);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        Products[i] = objs[i].value1;
        Prices[i] = objs[i].value2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(Products[i] + "\n" + Prices[i] + "\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы создаёте новый вопрос, если правильно было отредактировать [старый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/883188/213987)?

Comment: @AK Там я не знал саму логику, а тут просьба помочь с ошибкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Sort с одним параметром будет сравнивать структуры?

Ему нужно помочь, добавив функцию сравнения (делегат) примерно так:

```
Array.Sort(objs, new Comparison<Obj>((a, b) => a.price.CompareTo(b.price)));
```

([ideone](https://ideone.com/NbJOjk))

```
Bread 4
Milk 10
Chocolate 16
Meat 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, сама идея - создать структуру данных, объединяющую название и цену продукта - правильная.

Только я бы именования изменил:

```
struct Product
{
    public string Name;
    public int Price;
}
```

---

Однако ваш вопрос звучит так:

> сделать сортировку двух массивов одновременно

Это делается элементарно использованием перегрузки метода [Array.Sort](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2), которая принимает на вход два массива:

```
string[] products = new string[4] { "Meat", "Bread", "Milk", "Chocolate" };
int[] prices = new int[4] { 25, 4, 10, 16 };

Array.Sort(prices, products);

for (int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(products[i] + " " + prices[i]);
```

Первый массив будет отсортирован по возрастанию, а элементы второго переставлены в соответствии с первым.